# Setting value in multiple Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I using React Material-UI with react-hook-form, I can't `setValue` if using multiple attribute.

Can anyone help me.

This is my component:

```js
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        // console.log(field);
        // console.log('field.value', field.value);
        return (
          <AutocompleteMaterial
            disableClearable={disableClearable}
            {...field}

            onBlur={() => {
              if ((!field.value || (Array.isArray(field.value) && field.value.length === 0)) && persistValue) {
                field.onChange(persistValue);
              }
            }}
            multiple={multiple}
            freeSolo={false}
            filterSelectedOptions={multiple}
            disabled={disabled}
            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
            className="w100"
            onChange={(_e, data) => {
              // console.log('onChange', data);
              return field.onChange ? field.onChange(data) : () => {};
            }}
            renderInput={params => {
              return (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  className="style-ip"
                  variant="standard"
                  size={multiple ? 'small' : 'medium'}
                  helperText={error ? error.message : ''}
                  error={!!error}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
```

When I `setValue` without multiple `setValue('field', { title: 'title', value: 'value' });` . It's working well

When I `setValue` with multiple. I has been try set array or field but it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this since multiple values are stored in an array:

```
setValue('field', [{ title: 'title', value: 'value' }]);
```

**EDIT**: You also need to use [controlled mode](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states) to be able to update the value of `Autocomplete`. To do that, provide a non-empty value to the `value` props of `Autocomplete` at the initial render:

```
const { control, setValue } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    name: []
  }
});
```

```
<Controller
  name="name"
  control={control}
  render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => {
  ...
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67271709/setting-value-autocomple-multiple]

Comment: Thank you a lot. I find reason is options I get from api. Without multiple, it's ok. But with multiple, I need using useEffect to handle options change and setValue for autocomplete multiple ~~. I spent 3 days to fix this problem ~~. Thank you very much, this example help me a lot.